# Using property as a constant without calling a getter method which returns constant

Tags: objective-c, properties, constants

I have a constant in a class, that I defined it by `#define HEIGHT 65` And I know How I can get this out of this class by calling a getter method which returns this constant. I mean I don't want doing this:

```
#define HEIGHT 65

.
.
.

-(int)getHeight{
    return HEIGHT;
}
```

**But question is there a way for defining a constant `@property` and get it by `instanceClass.HEIGHT` like other `properties`.**

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) int height;
```

and then in the implementation file:

```
@dynamic height;

....

- (int)height {
    return HEIGHT;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean using `#define` for `HEIGHT`?

Comment: yes, I meant it; I think it is the cleanest solution, but if you like you can do `return 65;`...

Comment: Is `@dynamic` needed at all; You seem have fulfilled the requirement by providing the getter method?

Comment: I tested it. It worked without `@dynamic`. But i don't get my answer yet!

Comment: @HamedRajabi This is pretty much as Objective-C as you can get, however I think creating a class method would be better which means you don't have to instantiate an this object just to get the constant; you could use `[MyObject height]` instead, which is better.

Comment: `@dynamic` is not needed; I like to use it in such cases because it makes clearer my intention. @Hamed Rajabi: what was your question exactly? I mean, what I suggested allows you to use syntax property to have back a constant value; there is not an easier way, nothing like: `@property (...) int height=65;`, if you mean something like this...

Comment: Thanks @trojanfoe. I already have this `class` for whole program but not for certain `object`! I think this way isn't `Object Oriented`.

Comment: @sergio I mean something like `const int HEIGHT = 65` inside of `@property`, I don't know, perhaps there is no way to doing this!

Comment: @HamedRajabi I think this approach is the most object-oriented; alternatives are C-like using `#define` or `enum` which are simpler but not at all object-oriented.

Comment: I fear that declaring a value within the @property declaration is not allowed by Objective-C syntax, nor its runtime...

Comment: By the way thank you @sergio & @trojanfoe! I accept your answers!